# Excel - Macro to reorder columns, rows, dynamically with changing spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

My question is on how to reorder a spreadsheet using a VB macro.  The CSV spreadsheet is an order form from a customer of ours that is exported from their shipping software that needs to be uploaded into our shipping software for execution.

The issue I have come across in my very basic VB understanding is the extreme amount of redundancy I am using to try and write this.  I know how to remove rows, columns, etc.  What I do not know how to do is make it dynamic for an ever changing spreadsheet (I.E 20 orders in March, 40 orders in April)

Basically what needs to happen to the spreadsheet is the first 10 rows will need to be removed, you will need to keep row 11 and 12, then from there, you can see that there are names such as in row 12 "Coat and Tails", Bryce Dishongh, Address, etc. spanning across the rows.  These are the only rows that need to be kept in the spreadsheet, they are every 14 or 15 lines depending.

I was going through these just counting down how many, and deleting the rows to stack these specific rows, but you can see how redundant that coding is.

Is there a better solution that can dynamically change according to how many orders there many be per month?

The code I am using is:

```
Sub Delete()

Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete

Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete

Rows(3).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(3).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(3).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(3).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(3).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(3).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(3).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(3).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(3).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(3).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(3).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(3).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(3).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(3).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(3).EntireRow.Delete

Rows(4).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(4).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(4).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(4).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(4).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(4).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(4).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(4).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(4).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(4).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(4).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(4).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(4).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(4).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(4).EntireRow.Delete

Rows(5).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(5).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(5).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(5).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(5).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(5).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(5).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(5).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(5).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(5).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(5).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(5).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(5).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(5).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(5).EntireRow.Delete

Rows(6).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(6).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(6).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(6).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(6).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(6).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(6).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(6).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(6).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(6).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(6).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(6).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(6).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(6).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(6).EntireRow.Delete

Rows(7).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(7).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(7).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(7).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(7).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(7).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(7).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(7).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(7).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(7).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(7).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(7).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(7).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(7).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(7).EntireRow.Delete

Rows(8).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(8).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(8).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(8).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(8).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(8).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(8).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(8).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(8).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(8).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(8).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(8).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(8).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(8).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(8).EntireRow.Delete

Rows(9).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(9).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(9).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(9).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(9).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(9).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(9).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(9).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(9).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(9).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(9).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(9).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(9).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(9).EntireRow.Delete
Rows(9).EntireRow.Delete


End Sub
```

As you can see this is very redundant.  Is there anyway to clean this up?

Comment: You will have much more chance to get help if you show the code you currently attempt and discuss it a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Sub mySub()
    ' First, define an array for the words that you need to keep.
    Dim words: words = Array("Coat and Tails", "Bryce Dishongh", "Address") ' <-- etc..

    With ActiveSheet '<-- I hate this, but to simplify your task
       .Columns(1).Delete
       For i = .UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1 To 13 Step -1
            If Application.Sum(Application.CountIf(.Rows(i), words)) = 0 Then .Rows(i).Delete
       Next

       .Rows("1:10").Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very close.  The issue is that it only hit the first row of information that was needed, the rest of the spreadsheet went away with it.

Comment: Do you have an email I could provide the CSV file to you so that you may see for yourself?

Comment: Ah! excuse me, I was forgetting that the array is looking for specific data. Let me update and try again.

Comment: The code basically conserves the rows that contain **any** of the keywords you define in the array `words`. Wasn't that your requirement?